# Calculating roc curve with multi class variables

Tags: python, pandas, roc

I need to calculate the ROC Curve for two multiclass variables and I'm getting an error I haven't been able to work out.

Here's my code and the error I'm getting:

---

```
Input:
auc = roc_auc_score(df["two_year_recid"], df["decile_score"])
auc

Output:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-223ffcb55a4f> in <module>
----> 1 auc = roc_auc_score(df["is_recid"], df["decile_score"])
      2 auc

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py in roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight, max_fpr, multi_class, labels)
    379                              "instead".format(max_fpr))
    380         if multi_class == 'raise':
--> 381             raise ValueError("multi_class must be in ('ovo', 'ovr')")
    382         return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, labels,
    383                                          multi_class, average, sample_weight)

ValueError: multi_class must be in ('ovo', 'ovr')
```

both columns are int64.

---

I tried to implement OVR and calculate per-class roc_auc_score but it didn't work.

Can anyone please try to help out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From `sklearn` documentations [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

```
ROC curves are typically used in binary classification to study the output
of a classifier. In order to extend the ROC curve and ROC area to multi-label
classification, it is necessary to binarize the output.
```

The ROC (and, therefore, the AUC) may be used only for binary classification. To extend it to multi-class classification, please consider one-vs-all or many-vs-many binarization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kate! I'm not being able to binarize the output based on the info available on the link you sent me.

I tried this in the meantime and got a different error -not a multi class one any more.

def race_roc(racestr):
    race_sel = d["race"] == racestr
    X = (d["decile_score"]/9)[race_sel]
    y = d["is_recid"][race_sel]
    viz = ROCAUC(Identity(),classes=['No reoffense','Reoffense'])
    viz.fit(X,y)
    viz.score(X,y)
    viz.poof()
    plt.close()
race_roc("Caucasian")

error: name 'Identity' is not defined

Comment: I couldn't help you with that -- one needs to look into the code. `viz=ROCAUC(Identity(),...)` uses Identity class/function, and there is no access to this variable. Not imported? Not defined? It's hard to say without looking at your code.